# .map of an object in an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to loop through an object that contains arrays which contain objects inside of them in React and I get an error on the `.map` function. Here is the `.map` function followed by what the object looks like in `this.state`

.map:

```
//trying to access January from the object which is 0 starting month
let daysOfWeeks = this.state[0].map(function (day, i){
    ...
}
```

Here is an example of the object:

```
//0 is January, 1 is February, and so on... inside has objects that have the day number and day of week
let result = {
    0:[ 
        {dayNumber:1,dayOfWeek:"fri"},
        {dayNumber:2,dayOfWeek:"sat"},
        {dayNumber:3,dayOfWeek:"sun"},
        ...
      ],
    1:[
        {dayNumber:1,dayOfWeek:"mon"},
        {dayNumber:2,dayOfWeek:"tue"},
        {dayNumber:3,dayOfWeek:"wed"},
        ...
      ],
    2:[
        {dayNumber:1,dayOfWeek:"tue"},
        {dayNumber:2,dayOfWeek:"wed"},
        {dayNumber:3,dayOfWeek:"thur"},
        ...
      ],

    ...
};

//result is in a function that is returned and set state is calling the function and setting state to the object itself -- here is setState:

this.setState(getDaysArray(y,m));

//getDaysArray(y,m) returns that object above
```

What I want in the `.map` is for day to be the object I loop through. `day.dayNumber` and `day.dayOfWeek`

```
... .map(function(day, i){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>{day.dayNumber}</div>
            <div>{day.dayOfWeek}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But what errors in on the `.map` is `this.state[0]` I think is the issue. Anyone know how I can access and loop through the objects in the array inside the parent object?

Comment: What is in state? Is this.state === result? In that case, you should use this.state.map instead of this.state[0].map

Comment: whats the error? dont listen to the above comment, its wrong. Obviously you cannot map through an object.

Comment: using let daysOfWeeks = this.state[0].map(function (day, i){ ... the error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: using let daysOfWeeks = this.state.map(function (day, i){ ... the error is: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.map is not a function

Comment: this.state === result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `this.state.result['0'].map(...)`

When you have a an object like this, with a number as the key, even though the key is a 'number; you access it as a string. Object keys by default are strings.

```
let result = {
    0:[ 
        {dayNumber:1,dayOfWeek:"fri"},
        {dayNumber:2,dayOfWeek:"sat"},
        {dayNumber:3,dayOfWeek:"sun"},
        ...
      ]
}
```